# External JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, function, external

I'm developing a sound library with JavaScript. I created sound.js file and this file included in test.php file. sound.js file contains some function. My sound.js file like this:

```
var soundPath   = './sound/';

/*
 * Sounds Path
*/
var phoneNumberSound        = ['0.wav', '1.wav', '2.wav', '3.wav', '4.wav', '5.wav', '6.wav', '7.wav', '8.wav', '9.wav'];
// var phoneCallSound          = null;

/*
 * Play Phone Number's Sound
*/
function playPhoneNumberSound (phoneNumber)
{
    phoneNumber = parseInt(phoneNumber);
    if (phoneNumber.length > 1){
        var phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length - 1);
        new Audio(soundPath + phoneNumberSound[phoneNumber-1]).play();
    } else {
        new Audio(soundPath + phoneNumberSound[phoneNumber-1]).play();
    }
}

/*
 * Coming Phone Incoming Sound
*/
function playPhoneIncomingSound ()
{
    document.writeln('Test this func');
}
```

In test.php, i call above functions. First function is working but the second function or third or others... does not work. Browser error result is like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: playPhoneIncomingSound is not defined
```

My test.php file is like this:

```
<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/sound.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" />
<button id="playSound">Play Sound</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#playSound').click(function ()
        {
            playPhoneIncomingSound ();
            // var phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();
            // playPhoneNumberSound(phoneNumber);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why? Why this error occur? Where is my mistake?

Thank!

**Edit:**
This error about Chrome. When i clear browsersing data, this error be lost. In firebox, i didn't take like this error!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call `playPhoneIncomingSound()` using onclick?

```js
var soundPath = './sound/';

/*
 * Sounds Path
 */
var phoneNumberSound = ['0.wav', '1.wav', '2.wav', '3.wav', '4.wav', '5.wav', '6.wav', '7.wav', '8.wav', '9.wav'];
// var phoneCallSound          = null;

/*
 * Play Phone Number's Sound
 */
function playPhoneNumberSound(phoneNumber) {
  phoneNumber = parseInt(phoneNumber);
  if (phoneNumber.length > 1) {
    var phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length - 1);
    new Audio(soundPath + phoneNumberSound[phoneNumber - 1]).play();
  } else {
    new Audio(soundPath + phoneNumberSound[phoneNumber - 1]).play();
  }
}

/*
 * Coming Phone Incoming Sound
 */
function playPhoneIncomingSound() {
  document.writeln('Test this func');
}
```

```html
<button id="playSound" onclick="playPhoneIncomingSound()">Play Sound</button>
```

In your test.php code, the `playPhoneIncomingSound ();` is trying to find the function in the script tag code but not in sound.js

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work. The problem is with Chrome. Thanks dude!

Comment: what's the problem in chrome? any error in the console?